# magento2.3 mysql slow query

Tags: magento2.3, database, theme

```
SET timestamp=1708087305;
UPDATE `theme` SET `parent_id` = NULL, `theme_path` = 'Magento/blank', `theme_title` = 'Magento Blank', `preview_image` = 'preview_image_5d490e5c15226.jpeg', `is_featured` = '0', `area` = 'frontend', `type` = '0', `code` = 'Magento/blank' WHERE (theme_id='1');
# Time: 2024-02-16T12:43:01.426876Z

use database_name;
SET timestamp=1708088126;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `customer_visitor`;
# Time: 2024-02-16T12:57:56.894749Z
```

How to Fix this error..

Comment: Add more details about this.

Comment: The above queries are run daily and log are generate and  the load on the server increases. we getting error like... https://i.imgur.com/vqJ89az.png

Comment: what is the value of query_cache_type and query_cache_size of MySQL?

Comment: @MagecompProductTeam  Do you mean there are entries in Slow Query Log for the url you posted?  Please post TEXT result of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE theme; and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "theme";  for analysis.

Comment: Please also post TEXT results of SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "customer_visitor";

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide speed improvement suggestions.